# display input field on new line ( based on radio select )

Tags: javascript, css

Ok found some great code on Stack. Have adapted it slightly.

But in essence we have a radio box group, in a form. And onclick of one of these radio buttons, an input field is displayed.

I need to show this input field on a new line ( preferably with a new label too ) but struggling.

The code is: html

```
<div class="s_row_2 clearfix">
        <label><strong>Price</strong></label>
            <div class="s_full">
                <label class="s_radio"><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="r" id="r1" onchange="disableTxt()"/> Free</label>
                <label class="s_radio"><input type="radio" name="r" id="r2" onchange="disableTxt()"/> Swap / Trade</label>
                <label class="s_radio"><input type="radio" name="r" id="r3" onchange="disableTxt()"/> Lets Talk</label>
                <label class="s_radio"><input type="radio" name="r" id="r3" onchange="enableTxt()"/> Price</label>
                    <input type="text" name="r" id="price" style="display:none;width:212px;" size="30" placeholder="Type your price"/>
            </div>
    </div>
```

js:

```
var temp = '';
    function disableTxt() {
        var field = document.getElementById("price");
        if(field.value != '') {
            temp = field.value;
        }
        field.style.display = "none";
        field.value = '';
    }
    function enableTxt() {
        document.getElementById("price").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("price").value = temp;
    }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/mnxRr/

Essentially, I would prefer price as the first option. So that onclick the input field displays below the radio selections with a new label.

Any suggestions please

to recap sorry:

I prefer html like so:

```
<div class="s_full">
                <label class="s_radio"><input type="radio" name="r" id="r3" onchange="enableTxt()"/> Price</label>
                    <input type="text" name="r" id="price" style="display:none;width:212px;" size="30" placeholder="Type your price"/>
                <label class="s_radio"><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="r" id="r1" onchange="disableTxt()"/> Free</label>
                <label class="s_radio"><input type="radio" name="r" id="r2" onchange="disableTxt()"/> Swap / Trade</label>
                <label class="s_radio"><input type="radio" name="r" id="r3" onchange="disableTxt()"/> Lets Talk</label>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply reorder your radio buttons?

```
<div class="s_full">
    <label class="s_radio"><input type="radio" name="r" id="r3" onchange="enableTxt()"/> Price</label>
    <label class="s_radio"><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="r" id="r1" onchange="disableTxt()"/> Free</label>
    <label class="s_radio"><input type="radio" name="r" id="r2" onchange="disableTxt()"/> Swap / Trade</label>
    <label class="s_radio"><input type="radio" name="r" id="r3" onchange="disableTxt()"/> Lets Talk</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="r" id="price" style="display:none;width:212px;" size="30" placeholder="Type your price"/>
</div>
```

seems to do the trick, doesn't it?

Comment: No. It displays the input inline. The input needs to be displayed on new line at worse, or wrapped in its own <div class="s_row_2 clearfix">
        <label><strong>Enter Price</strong></label>
</div>

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem: you want the input field on a new line? There is a `<br />` after the last radio button which should make sure that this happens. Also, you could set the `display` property to `block` instead of `inline`in your `enableTxt()` definition. If you need a label on the input field, wrap label and input field in a div and use this wrapper's id instead of the `"price"` in your code.

Comment: Tried that, but perhaps its the block issue. Will give it a whirl Julian

Comment: Nope, and adding a br rendered outside of display none cocks up layout. Will try and append it to a hidden div.

Comment: Chose your answer, I figured it out. Thanks mate